# How would you draw a oval from the following coordinates?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm attempting to use the media module in python to draw an oval form these coordinates.

(244,88) to (288,44)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import media
from color import *

z=media.create_picture(640, 400, white)
media.add_oval_filled(y, 288, 44, 44, 88, black)

media.show(z)
```

I know this is not right, but how could I make a circle from the coordinates stated above. This would produce a oval, that is slanted. (Please only use the media module and color!)

Comment: Are we to presume you mean the [PyGraphics `media` module](http://packages.python.org/PyGraphics/user/media.html)? What do you mean from point to point? Is that centre -> point on circumference, or top-left to bottom-right of the encasing square?

Comment: Do you want it to fit in a box bound by those corners? Do you want it to touch those two points? You need to be more detailed than "draw an oval from these coordinates".

Comment: @Justin +1, said just as I edited my comment. It's also worth noting, why the restriction to `media` and `color`? Is this homework? If so, tag it as such.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to know how to draw an oval from variable coordinates (say, _x_ and _y_) rather than specifically (244, 88) and (288, 44)?

Comment: I want it to touch those two points, forming an oval. And yes the PyGraphics media module. And I would like to know how to form the oval from those coordinates.

Comment: Also yes it is homework?

Comment: Two points are not enough to fully specify a non-axis-aligned oval. If we assume the given points are the endpoints of the major axis, we still need to know the length of the minor axis.

Comment: (... in the simplest case, the major and minor axis lengths are identical, and you can just draw a circle with the two points defining a diameter.)

Comment: Is there a function that can draw semi circles?

Comment: You mean "arcs"? I'm sure there is.

Comment: Also, there are an infinite number of ovals that can pass through any two distinct points.

Comment: What function would I be using for arcs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw an ellipse from (244,88) to (288,44), your width and height should be 44 and 44 and not 44 and 88. So Try this

```
z=media.create_picture(640, 400, white)
media.add_oval_filled(z, 244, 88, 44, 44, black)
media.show(z)
```

For drawing arcs use `pygame` module.

To draw a partial section of an ellipse, Use

```
pygame.draw.arc(Surface, color, Rect, start_angle, stop_angle, width)
```